# Is there a problem with posting SharePoint's decomplied code in answers?

Tags: discussion, source-code

We can learn a lot by examining the source of the product. Is there any problem with answers that refer, link, or even quote, code that comes from decompiled SharePoint's assemblies?

Answer (score 4):

You would have to dig into the Product Use Rights (PUR) or MicroSoft Licensing Terms (MSLT) or End User License Agreement (EULA) for the specific product to answer that.

Marc Arend posted an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2008/02/28/using-reflector-to-see-sharepoint-s-source-code.aspx) on using reflector some years back, where he stipulated that you should be careful to read about this before using Reflector, let alone post code extracted by reflector.

What i am trying to say is, that there probably is a grey area here, but that you shold thread carefully as not to violate any MS propriatory rights.

[SharePoint server 20101 PUR](http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/userights/ProductPage.aspx?pid=320)

Comment: So, if *I* post the code. For the discussion, lets ignore problems I might cause to myself and to my organization - is there a problem for the this site, holding the code? Would you flag or delete such posts? (or maybe I'm self-censoring). By the way, I'm referring to this post (by me): http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12663/is-it-possible-to-use-docidredir-aspx-for-linking-to-the-display-form/12730#12730

Comment: What you describe in your answer is what every decent SharePoint developer faces and does on a daily basis: checking how things are tied together "under the hood". I see no problems doing that or writing about doing that, or even telling others to do that. where it gets hazy is when you start to post either internal code from reflector or deobfuscating code.

Comment: What I tend to do is to try to explain in English what a particular bit of the SharePoint code does, hinting at specific Type names to encourage people to have a dig through and see for themselves.